# React-hook-form v7 does not update form value on submit

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a dynamic form, where the values ​​come from the backend and so I create the form...

However, I also have a switch case, where I change the input mask when the user switches the interface.

Well... everything is working correctly, the user is able to change the mask and the value is updated in the interface, however, when submitting the form, the old values ​​are being delivered, before the mask.

**INPUT CONTROLLER**

```
interface IProps {
    controller: {
        name: FieldName<FieldValues>;
        control: Control<FieldValues, object>;
        defaultValue: string;
    };
    tooltip: Pick<IControllerContainerProps, 'placement' | 'label' | 'title'>;
    tabIndex: number;
    required: boolean;
    disabled: boolean;
    placeholder: string;
    mask: {
        isDate: boolean;
        isPercentage: boolean;
        isNumber: boolean;
        isCurrency: boolean;
    };
}

const InputMaskControllerForm = ({ controller, tooltip, mask, ...props }: IProps) => {
    const propsByMask = useMemo(
        () => ({
            allowNegative: !mask.isDate,
            decimalSeparator: mask.isDate ? undefined : ',',
            decimalScale: mask.isDate ? undefined : 2,
            fixedDecimalScale: !mask.isDate,
            format: mask.isDate ? '##/##/####' : undefined,
            prefix: mask.isCurrency ? 'R$' : undefined,
            mask: mask.isDate ? ['D', 'D', 'M', 'M', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'] : undefined,
            suffix: mask.isPercentage ? '%' : undefined,
            thousandSeparator: mask.isDate ? false : '.',
        }),
        [mask]
    );

    const rules = useMemo(
        () => ({
            pattern: {
                value: mask.isDate ? /^[d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}]+$/i : /[0-9]+/i,
                message: mask.isDate ? 'Data inválida' : 'Valor inválido',
            },
            required: {
                value: props.required,
                message: 'Campo Obrigatório',
            },
        }),
        [mask, props]
    );

    return (
        <Controller
            {...controller}
            rules={rules}
            render={({ field, fieldState: { error }, formState: { errors } }) => (
                <FormControllerContainer {...tooltip} errorMessage={errors[controller.name]?.message}>
                    <InputMask {...field} {...propsByMask} {...props} $error={!!error} />
                </FormControllerContainer>
            )}
        />
    );
};
```

**FORM**

```
const FORM_UNIQUE_NAME = 'STRUCTURE_PARAMETER';
const { control, handleSubmit, watch } = useFormContext();
const [inputMaskType, setInputMaskType] = useState<InputMaskType>('isCurrency');

const onSubmit = (data: any) => console.log(data);
const handleOnChangeMask = useCallback((stateValue: string) => setInputMaskType(stateValue as InputMaskType), []);

const inputMask = useCallback(
    (isParameterNumber: boolean): IStructureParameterMask => {
        const MASK: IStructureParameterMask = {
            isCurrency: false,
            isDate: false,
            isNumber: false,
            isPercentage: false,
        };

        if (!isParameterNumber) {
            MASK[inputMaskType] = true;
            return MASK;
        }

        MASK.isNumber = true;
        return MASK;
    },
    [inputMaskType]
);

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} autoComplete='off' noValidate>
{selectStructureFormData?.value.parameters.map(({ id, order, name, description, htmlControl }) => (
        <InputMaskControllerForm
        tabIndex={order}
        mask={inputMask(htmlControl.mask.isNumber)}
        placeholder={htmlControl.placeholder}
        disabled={htmlControl.isDisabled}
        required={htmlControl.isRequired}
        controller={{
            name: `${FORM_UNIQUE_NAME}.${id}`,
            control,
            defaultValue: '',
        }}
        tooltip={{
            title: name,
            label: description,
            placement: 'top-left',
        }}
    />
        )}
</form>;
```

**INSERT DATA IN INPUTS:**

[image]

**CHANGE OF MASK:**

[image]

Comment: check out formik for this operation. it is a perfect library for this and heavily in use in the react community.

Comment: have you tried to use useMemo instead of useCallback?